# How to write an if/else statement in terraform to deploy a specific resource

Tags: azure, terraform, infrastructure-as-code

I am trying to write an **if** statement in Terraform to deploy or not to deploy a specific resource and struggling to get it to work.

I want to deploy a subnet called **AzureFirewallSubnet** using an if statement. If the condition is **true** and do not deploy if the condition is **false** and currently I cannot get it to work.

**main.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
    name = var.vnet.name
    location = var.rg.location
    resource_group_name = var.rg.name
    address_space = var.vnet.address_space  

    subnet {
        count = "${var.afw_subnet.enabled == true ? 1 : 0}"
        name = var.subnets.subnet1.name
        address_prefix = var.subnets.subnet1.address_prefix
    }
}
```

**parameters.tf**

```
# Virtual Network Paramters
variable "vnet" {
    default = {
        name = "vnet-uks-prod-hub-01"
        address_space = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
    }
}

# Azure Firewall
variable "afw_subnet" {
    default = {
        enabled = true
    }
}

# Subnet Parameters
variable "subnets" {
    type = map
    default = {
        subnet1 = {
            name = "AzureFirewallSubnet"
            address_prefix = "10.0.0.0/26"
        }
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
 Error: Unsupported argument
 
   on vnet-hub/vnet_hub.tf line 15, in resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet":
   15:         count = "${var.afw_subnet.enabled == true ? 1 : 0}"
 
 An argument named "count" is not expected here.

##[error]Terraform command 'validate' failed with exit code '1'.
```

If there is a better way of doing this without using count, it would be great if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a [dynamic block](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks) should get you there.

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = var.vnet.name
  location            = var.rg.location
  resource_group_name = var.rg.name
  address_space       = var.vnet.address_space


  dynamic "subnet" {
    for_each = var.afw_subnet.enabled ? [1] : []

    content {
      name           = var.subnets.subnet1.name
      address_prefix = var.subnets.subnet1.address_prefix
    }
  }
}
```

A better way yet would be to add one such block for each subnet given in `subnets`. Like this:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = var.vnet.name
  location            = var.rg.location
  resource_group_name = var.rg.name
  address_space       = var.vnet.address_space


  dynamic "subnet" {
    for_each = var.subnets

    content {
      name           = subnet.name
      address_prefix = subnet.address_prefix
    }
  }
}
```